# Visual Studio 2015 - removing remote project references from a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a solution with remote project references (which I added by right clicking and selecting 'Add to solution'). Now, I am attempting to remove the projects from the solution and I am unable. Here is what I have tried:

1) Right click on the references and select "remove".
2) Close Visual Studio
3) Reopen Visual Studio and there they are is if I didn't remove them???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear to tell from distance; try to edit the `.csproj` files manually.